# customized terminal to map long CLI terminal command to a short one

Tags: ubuntu, user-interface, terminal, command-line-interface, alias

I have a program in Linux that take arguments and i need to shorten these commands (think alias) but not as part of the existing shell or modifying bashrc .

example :
existing situation

```
>>run program a with argument "time 10"
>> result :  x = 20
```

```
>>run program a with argument "average 5"
>> result : x = 30
```

what i need is open a new customized terminal like a built in GUI to shorten the commands
example

```
>>time 10
>> x = 20
```

```
>>average 5
>> x =30
```

the new GUI internally
-- will take  ( time 10 --> change it to : "run program a with argument "time 10" ) and show results

basically aliasing on demand in a customized terminal and once its done and closed we are back to normal

thanks in advance for any pointers

Answer (score 0):

Create a bash script in your `/usr/bin` directory:

Just name the bash script what you want to type in to the terminal, and make it excecutable: (You can create the file in VIM or whatever editor IE Nano etc etc )

```
$ vi /usr/bin/filename
```

OR

```
$ nano /usr/bin/filename
```

Inside the file .. Make a small program and save:

```
#!/bin/bash
arg=$1

echo "running the program a with argument of $arg"
```

When you are done .. Make sure it's executable:

```
$ chmod +x filename
```

Then you should be able to:

```
$ filename 10
$ running the program a with argument of 10
```

Comment: Hi Zak, thats so much for the reply . that worked :) .

Comment: can the actual script be run once and the commands are run without calling the script everytime ?  example "run file name" that opens a built in terminal where you can issue commands directly example : "time 10" , instead of "filename time 10"

Comment: `time` is a reserved linux command ..   I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: time is just an example .. it can be anything .  example : run filename , an interface like gdb will open and i just issue commands directly without putting filename in the front

Comment: What's the purpose?  Why wouldn't you just use a shell?  That's what it's designed for. Whether you create your "faux shell within a shell" or it's just a shell .. The outcome is the same.  You're trying to reinvent a wheel that works perfectly well for your needs.